# Datepicker's format on initialization

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a table in my db with a column `date`. When I edit this table, the value of the input has this format: `yy-mm-dd`. In my js file I initialize the datepicker:

```
$('#date-input').datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            isRTL : $('body').hasClass('rtl') ? true : false,
            prevText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
            nextText: '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
            showButtonPanel: false,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
```

As you can see, I've specified the format: `dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'`, but it works only when I select the date from the picker. Is there any way I can set a propper date format, so on edit the date will be, for example, `01-09-2018`, but not `2018-09-01`? Thanks.

Comment: So the date that come from db is in `yy-mm-dd` and you want to show it in `dd-mm-yy` format, right?

Comment: @Pavan, exactly

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi what framework are you using? i mean c#, mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the right format on the edit template. Suppose you are using form_for with an object:

```
f.text_field :some_date, @object.some_date.to_formatted_s('dd-mm-yy')
```

Then the initial date will be one that can be understood by datepicker's format config.

You can make it less hardcoded using localization:

```
f.text_field :some_date, l(@object.some_date, format: :input)
# `l` method is a shortcut for I18n.l, a shortcut for I18n.localize
```

and then have a date format on your es.yml (I guess you are not developing an english app given that format):

```
es:
  date:
    formats:
      input: 'dd-mm-yy'
```

That way you can change the format in one place and even accept diferent languages (you could use the localization format instead of hardcoding the format on your script too).